# Преобразование времени в число в SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Вычислила время работы в секундах, теперь нужно перевести секунды в `decimal`, чтобы можно было видеть время работы, например как 0,25 часа. Не соображу, как тут использовать функцию `CONVERT`

```
SUM((DATEPART(hh, r.d)*3600)+(DATEPART(mi, r.d)*60) + (DATEPART(ss, r.d))) as vremya
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Время в часах = 1/(3600/Время в секундах)

То есть по Вашему примеру:
a=900 (90 сек = 15 минут = 0,25 часа)

Время в часах= 1/(3600/900)=1/4 =0.25 часа

Ну а в код думаю переведете сами ;)

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

в одном часе 60*60=3600 секунд. отношение вычисленного времени в секундах к числу секунд в одном часе и будет решением

```
SELECT vremya/3600. (с точкой на конце)
```